# Using the Linux kernel make system for userspace tools

Tags: linux, build, makefile

I've seen several projects for userspace tools (though I cannot, unfortunately, seem to remember which ones at this time) which appear to be reusing the Linux kernel make-system, as evidenced by the similarity in build messages:

```
  CC       foo1.o
  CC       foo2.o
  LINK     foo
```

You know.

Is there any "well-known" procedure for doing so? Is there some standard repository of makefiles and such that can be reused in a well-defined manner to do this? I've tried googling around about it, but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel build system is pretty mission specific.  I'm not sure of any projects that leverage it.

Many projects use autotools -- automake and autoconf -- to handle building.  If you've ever run `./configure` to build a project, you've encountered them.  It turns out that automake generated Makefiles have a mode for emitting the "Linux-style" build messages: `make V=0`.

This can be set to be the default behavior: https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Automake-silent_002drules-Option.html

You can certainly use autotools for your own projects.  A good starter guide is here:

http://smalltalk.gnu.org/blog/bonzinip/all-you-should-really-know-about-autoconf-and-automake

Comment: Thanks, but I'm well aware of the autotools and have used them many times. While it's true that I didn't know about automake's message silencing, I'm sure, at least, that these projects I speak of didn't use autotools, seeing as how they had no `configure` script. I'm also pretty sure that the `Makefile` of at least one of them bore clear similarities to the kernel's makefiles. It's a pity I can't seem to remember which ones they were...